# How can I hide columns in Openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm hiding a bunch of columns in an Excel sheet. I'm getting this error: `AttributeError: can't set attribute` from this line `worksheet.column_dimensions['B'].visible = False`

Sorry if this is a super simple question. I just updated to a new version of Openpyxl/Pandas so i'm now having to go through my code and make changes to fit the new version's documentation.

```
    worksheet.column_dimensions['B'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['D'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['E'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['F'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['G'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['H'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['I'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['K'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['L'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['M'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['N'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['O'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['P'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['Q'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['R'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['S'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['T'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['U'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['V'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['W'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['X'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['Y'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['Z'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['AA'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['AB'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['AC'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['AD'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['AE'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['AF'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['AG'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['AH'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['AI'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['AJ'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['AK'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['AM'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['AN'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['AP'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['AQ'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['AR'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['AS'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['AT'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['AU'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['AV'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['AW'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['AX'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['AY'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['AZ'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['BA'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['BB'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['BC'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['BD'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['BE'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['BF'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['BH'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['BI'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['BJ'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['BK'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['BL'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['BM'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['BN'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['BO'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['BP'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['BQ'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['BR'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['BS'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['BT'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['BU'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['BV'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['BW'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['BX'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['BY'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['BZ'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['CA'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['CB'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['CC'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['CD'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['CE'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['CF'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['CG'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['CH'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['CI'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['CJ'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['CK'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['CL'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['CM'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['CN'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['CO'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['CP'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['CQ'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['CR'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['CS'].visible = False
    worksheet.column_dimensions['CU'].visible = False
```

Also, if someone could tell me if there's a more efficient way to hide the columns, which i'm certain there probably is, that would be great.

Comment: Please use a for loop for your code

Comment: So I would add all of the columns that I want to hide into an array and then loop through the array to hide each one correct?

Comment: Yes and try the answer from DeepSpace

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should set the `hidden` attribute to `True`:

```
 worksheet.column_dimensions['A'].hidden= True
```

In order to hide more than one column:

```
for col in ['A', 'B', 'C']:
    worksheet.column_dimensions[col].hidden= True
```

Comment: Seems like not all column need to be hidden, ie `col['C']`, `col['AL']`
We might need more information about the logic behind which column to hide

Comment: @pwnsauce I never suggested that all columns should be hidden. This is up to OP to decide. I just showed them how.

Comment: @pwnsauce I don't think that is the actual problem of OP

Comment: ow, sorry, my bad.

Comment: Perfect! That worked for me! This is slightly off topic but my code is now giving me this error `ImportError: No module named style`

Comment: @hleggs You should probably open a new question, and include the exact error and the versions of Python/pandas/openpyxl that you are currently using, as this is a common error when using mismatching versions of the three.

Comment: @DeepSpace will do! Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 13):

Columns can be grouped:

```
ws.column_dimensions.group(start='B', end='CU', hidden=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a loop for a defined workbook wb.
in this example I have 10 columns with data and want to hidden all the remaining
16385 is the index of the last excel column, XFD, +1.

```
import openpyxl as op

worksheet = wb['Sheet1']

max_column =ws.max_column

last_column = op.utils.cell.column_index_from_string('XFD')

for idx in range(max_column+1, last_column+1):
    ws.column_dimensions[op.utils.get_column_letter(idx)].hidden = True
```

if you know the positions of your columns then will be easy