# How to hide rows with a cell with specific values?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to hide rows that have a cell that has the value `"MASK"` in my `WorkBook`.

```
def hide_rows_with_MASK(wb):
    for ws in wb:
        for row in ws.rows:
            if not rowShouldBeHidden(row): continue
            print("hide the row:",row)
            #row.hidden = True
                

def rowShouldBeHidden(row):
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == "MASK": return True
    return False
```

This code is working except the `hidden` part. Actually `row` is not an object but a `tuple` of cells.

[This post shows how to hide columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38527725/how-can-i-hide-columns-in-openpyxl/38527841) but I didn't manage to make it work for my example. I can find an ugly solution by hiding the cells but I feel there is a good way to do it (I just don't know it yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide a row you can use `RowDimension.hidden` attribute. You can have a look at `dimensions` submodule [documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions.html?highlight=row_dimensions#openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions.Dimension).

I would do something like below :

```
def hide_rows_with_MASK(wb):
    for ws in wb:
        for i, row in enumerate(ws.rows):
            if rowShouldBeHidden(row):
                print(f"Hiding row {i + 1}")
                #  openpyxl indexes are 1 based not 0
                ws.row_dimensions[i+1].hidden = True
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed :)